# c# input validation for strings and integers

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am trying to validate string and integer input

For string input, I am trying to implement a validation that do not accept null or integers and this is what i have for now which doesn't have error handling for integers:

```
string name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                if (name.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be an empty field, try again!");
                    name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    return; }
```

and for the integer input, I would like to only accept integers and my problem is that these codes  only allow me to enter a wrong input once before it shows me an error handing exception error

```
Console.Write("Enter exp: ");
                int exp = 0;
                try
                {
                    exp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid exp, please enter a valid numerical value!: ");
                    exp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
```

How should I handle all these input errors or are there any improvements I can make to my codes that I have for now?
All help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Enter exp: ");
    int exp;
    bool result = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out exp)
      if(result)
      {
       //you have an int value entered
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number")
      }
      //code continues
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @MarkRotteveel, i'll do better in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop until the user enters an integer.
And you should never use try...catch to check if an integer can be parsed. Always use `int.TryParse(...)`. Everything else is a code smell (and slower in the case when it is not an integer).

```
var integerEntered = false;
int exp;
while (!integerEntered)
{
    Console.Write("Enter exp: ");
    var entered = Console.ReadLine();
    integerEntered = int.TryParse(entered, out exp);
    if (!integerEntered)
        Console.WriteLine("That was no valid integer. Please try again.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *extracting methods*, e.g.

For string values input

```
private static string ReadString(string title, 
                                 Func<string, string> errorMessage = null) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console(title);

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    string message = errorMessage == null 
      ? null
      : errorMessage(input);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
      return input;    

    Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
}
```

For integer values

```
private static string ReadInt(string title, Func<x, string> errorMessage = null) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console(title);

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(input, out int result)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Not valid integer value. Please, try again.");

      continue;
    }

    string message = errorMessage == null 
      ? null
      : errorMessage(result);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
      return input;    

    Console.WriteLine(message);
  }
}
```

Then you can use them

```
string name = ReadString("Please, enter name", 
  v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v) 
     ? "Name cannot be an empty field, try again!" 
     : "");

int exp = ReadInt("Enter exp: ", v => v < 0 ? "Exp must not be negative", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code to have a function for each of your questions.

```cs
//input
get_input_func(){
string str = Console.ReadLine();
}

//validate
validation_func() {
try {
if(str.Length == 0 ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot be empty, please enter a num");
}
if(str.All(!Char.IsDigit)) {
    Console.WriteLine("You can only enter numbers");
    
}
//catch multiple exceptions
catch(Exception e) {
    switch(e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    get_input_func();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.